# Need a simple wiki system to replace DokuWiki to integreate with my homepage

Tags: wiki

Currently I'm using DokuWiki to manage my apps/scripts documentation, some articles I write and stuff like that... I like DokuWiki very much, it's simple and powerful but it's still too much for the use I've given it in the last 1/2 years.

I need something else, something different...

I'm looking for a way to integrate the little things I like in DokuWiki into my own website without needing a script, like DokuWiki, with it's own admin page. The website itself, my homepage, I like to code myself most of the things so it becomes exactly what I want. However, somethings I don't have much time for, that is why I'm using DokuWiki.

I want to ditch DokuWiki and scripts like these because I don't even use half of their capabilities. A wiki is a platform where people join their efforts and collaborate together to write stuff, it also has a revision system. These are two very important aspects about wikis that I don't care about for my own. I'm the only one writing stuff there and I don't care about revisions, never needed them.

What I like about DokuWiki is that I can point my browser to any URL within the wiki domain and create a page from there if it doesn't exist. I also like DokuWiki's syntax very much but sometimes it's very limited and I can't do what I want. The way you link between namespaces and such is also very nice. Too finish, a media/file manager is also very handy. These are probably the most important aspects for me in DokuWiki.

Basically, I'm looking for something, maybe a script, that would allow me to do the stuff I described above in a way I could integrate into my own website without needing a special administration area.

Does anyone know about such thing or I'm better off coding my own since my requirements are not that tricky to begin with, I just didn't want to have the extra work...

Or maybe any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll want to have a look at something like [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/), which is a single-file wiki, that you can even put on a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I chose xwiki over dokuwiki.

Another simple wiki is the one included with fogbugz.  It is hosted for free for up to 2 users and might suit your project.

Comment: I'm not looking for hosted stuff, I want to integrate it my own website... I'm thinking of building myself some kind of modules and that way I easily integrate with my own website.

Answer (score 0):

I may be off but very simple wiki with no administration and no users is [LionWiki](http://lionwiki.0o.cz/). I don't know how easy it's gonna be to integrate it into your website.

It's just one file and does not use database (like DokuWiki).

It does not have a lot of features though. It also uses a different syntax from that of DokuWiki.